# How to combine the result of one HTTP call to update several cells?

Tags: pandas

I have a CSV file that has a column `id`. I create a new one (`m0`), which contents come from an HTTP call with `id` as a parameter:

```py
d['m0'] = d['id'].apply(lambda id: pd.read_json(f"http://localhost:3000/{id}").get('H', {}).get('M0', "X"))
```

I need to also create columns `m1` and `m2` in a similar way. I could do

```py
d['m0'] = d['id'].apply(lambda id: pd.read_json(f"http://localhost:3000/{id}").get('H', {}).get('M0', "X"))
d['m1'] = d['id'].apply(lambda id: pd.read_json(f"http://localhost:3000/{id}").get('H', {}).get('M1', "X"))
d['m2'] = d['id'].apply(lambda id: pd.read_json(f"http://localhost:3000/{id}").get('H', {}).get('M2', "X"))
```

but the HTTP call is very expensive and slow (I have quite a lot of data).

**Is there a way to combine all three calls in one?**, knowing that this structure of the JSON I get, for a given `id`, is

```json
"H": {
  "M0": "sjkdhfjkshd",
  "M1": "isudfyfsdif",
  "M2": "azednbzaebe"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a common function, make an HTTP call, extract all required fields and return result as a pandas `Series`:

```py
def get_all_fields(row):
  h_json = pd.read_json(f"http://localhost:3000/{row['id']}").get('H', {})
  return pd.Series([
      h_json.get('M0', "X"),
      h_json.get('M1', "X"),
      h_json.get('M2', "X"),
  ])

d[['m0', 'm1', 'm2']] = d.apply(lambda row: get_all_fields(row), axis=1)
```